# $\left( 1 - \frac{1}{n} \right)\left( 1 - \frac{2}{n} \right) \cdot ... \cdot \left( 1 - \frac{k-1}{n} \right) = \frac{n!}{n^k r! (n-k-r)!}$

Tags: analysis, polynomials, binomial-coefficients, interpolation, approximation-theory

I'm trying to understand a proof in "Interpolation and Approximation by Polynomials" by Phillips.

Let me quote (page 253):

"For $k\geq 1$ we begin with $$B_{n+k}^{(k)}(f;x)=\frac{(n+k)!}{n!} \sum\limits_{r=0}^n \Delta^k f \left( \frac{r}{n+k} \right) \binom{n}{r} x^r (1-x)^{n-r}$$ and replace $n$ by $n-k$. 
Then, using $$\frac{\Delta^m f(x_0)}{h^m}=f^{(m)}(\xi)$$ with $h=1/n$, we write $$\Delta^k f \left( \frac{r}{n} \right) = \frac{f^{(k)}(\xi_r)}{n^k},$$ where $r/n<\xi_r<(r+k)/n$. 
Thus $$B_n^{(k)}(f;x)=\sum\limits_{r=0}^{n-k} c_k f^{(k)}(\xi_r) x^r (1-x)^{n-k-r}$$ [...]."

While he defines $c_0=c_1=1$ and $c_k=\left( 1 - \frac{1}{n} \right)\left( 1 - \frac{2}{n} \right) \cdot ... \cdot \left( 1 - \frac{k-1}{n} \right), 2 \leq k\leq n.$

I don't understand this because:

If i replace $n$ by $n-k$:
$$B_{n}^{(k)}(f;x)=\frac{(n)!}{(n-k)!} \sum\limits_{r=0}^{n-k} \Delta^k f \left( \frac{r}{n} \right) \binom{n-k}{r} x^r (1-x)^{n-r}$$

Than insert $\frac{f^{(k)}(\xi_r)}{n^k}$:
$$B_{n}^{(k)}(f;x)=\frac{(n)!}{(n-k)!} \sum\limits_{r=0}^{n-k} \frac{f^{(k)}(\xi_r)}{n^k} \binom{n-k}{r} x^r (1-x)^{n-r}$$

Now that his equality would be correct it has to be:
$c_k = \frac{n!}{(n-k)!n^k}\binom{n-k}{r}$

Why this should hold? I'm not even seeing why the $r$ shoudl dissapear.

Sincerely,
154085

Comment: I think I just found the mistake. Phillips just forgot the term $\binom{n-k}{r}$. Adding this the equation which has to hold is $c_k=\frac{n!}{(n-k)!n^k}$ and this seems to be true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sure that you have seen that :

$$c_k:=\prod_{i=1}^{k-1}(1-\frac{i}{n})=\frac{1}{n^{k-1}}\prod_{i=1}^{k-1}(n-i)=\frac{1}{n^k}\prod_{i=0}^{k-1}(n-i)=\frac{1}{n^k}\frac{n!}{(n-k)!} $$

So if you want :

$$c_k=\frac{n!}{(n-k)!n^k}\begin{pmatrix}n-k\\r\end{pmatrix}  $$

This leads to :

$$\begin{pmatrix}n-k\\r\end{pmatrix}=1\Rightarrow r=0\text{ or } r=n-k  $$

In particular your last remark is right, there is no reason for the $r$ to disappear. There must be the $\begin{pmatrix}n-k\\r\end{pmatrix}$  term missing in the formula given in the book.